# Не обновляется вся локаль после изменения ее в системных нсатройках

Tags: android, locale, settings

Предположим, системная локаль на текущий момент английская. Все надписи в активити - естестевенно на английском.
Сворачиваю активити - захожу в системные настройки - меняю язык на русский - возвращаюсь в активити - и в итоге не все надписи обновляются на русский.

- с чем это может быть связано?
- как решить проблему или так должно быть?

p.s. Все надписи переведены на русский и английский  и находятся в strings.xml (все стандартно). При перезапуске именно приложения - все нормально.

Comment: Может не все надписи переведены на русский? Или вообще не через `strings.xml` вставляются.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: А какие именно надписи не обновляются? Можете добавить скриншот. `android:configChanges` не устанавливали в манифесте?

Comment: Надписи которые берутся из getString(int resId); Нет, не устанавливал.

Comment: А какие тогда обновляются?

Comment: Все надписи берутся из getString(), некоторые обновляются, некоторые - нет. Могу предположить еще - что возможно разные  контексты, надо будет как-то потестить позже...

Comment: У меня как-раз похожая ситуация: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504024/android-localization-problem-not-all-items-in-the-layout-update-properly-when-s